# Онлайн вычисление

Tags: javascript

Есть пустой input в которое вводится значение и нужно с этим значением в режиме онлайн (без перезагрузки страницы) проделать некую математическую операцию (не важно какую пусть это будет умножение)...
То есть вводим 10 и сразу выводится в соседнем input'e результат, если меняем значение то результат сразу меняется
Одно из значений в формулу подгружаю из php через ajax
Никак не могу сообразить как это реализовать

Comment: [oninput event](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var input = document.body.children[0];
    
input.oninput = function() {
   document.getElementById('result').value = input.value*5;
};
```

```html
<input type="text">   <input id="result" type="text">
```

Comment: Спасибо, оказывается всё очень просто