# Данные из input в реальном времени

Tags: javascript, input

Делаю небольшой конвертер величин.

Пользователь должен ввести в input`е интересующее его значение, а в ячейках справа должны отобразится значения в других единицах измерений.

Когда ввожу значение в поле и нажимаю на кнопку, чтобы произвелись расчёты, то показываются нули. Когда обновляю страницу, то число в поле остаётся, нажимаю далее на кнопку - и расчёты проводятся.

Почему конвертер не работает в режиме реального времени? И как мне лишить калькулятор такого рода недостатка?

```
<table id="tableCalc">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Киловатт-час</td>
    <td>Джоуль</td>
    <td>Килокалория</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p>Киловатт-час</p><input id="KH" type="text"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td id="KH_to_JL"></td>
    <td id="KH_to_CL"></td>
    <td><button id="calculation_KH">Рассчёт</button></td>
</tr>


var KH = document.getElementById("KH").value;

var KH_to_JL = KH * 3600000;
var KH_to_CL = KH * 859.8;

$("#calculation_KH").click(function() {
    $("#KH_to_JL").text(KH_to_JL);
    $("#KH_to_CL").text(KH_to_CL);
})
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745171/%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/745173#745173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере нужно сделать так если повешать на кнопку "Рассчёт".  Если нужно сразу при вводе, смотрите пример выше по ссылки.

В примере используется [jquery 2.1.1](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js).

```js
var KH = 0;
var KH_to_JL = 0; 
var KH_to_CL = 0; 

$("#calculation_KH").click(function() {
    KH = document.getElementById("KH").value;
    
    KH_to_JL = KH * 3600000;
    KH_to_CL = KH * 859.8;

    $("#KH_to_JL").text(KH_to_JL);
    $("#KH_to_CL").text(KH_to_CL);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableCalc">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Киловатт-час</td>
    <td>Джоуль</td>
    <td>Килокалория</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p>Киловатт-час</p><input id="KH" type="text"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td id="KH_to_JL"></td>
    <td id="KH_to_CL"></td>
    <td><button id="calculation_KH">Рассчёт</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Да, работает. Спс. И в чём же принципиальная разница? Вижу, что 1) все переменные изначально обнулены, 2) дальнейшие действия над ними производятся в теле функции. Правильно ли я понял, что этих условий достаточно для того, чтобы калькулятор работал без обновлений?

Comment: @Kniga В вашем примере переменная KH присваивается один раз при загрузки страницы.   Получается поле input пусто,  пустоту умножает на  859.8, получается переменная KH_to_CL будет пустая.  При клики на кнопку к td c id "KH_to_CL"  присваивается пустота.

Comment: @Kniga если ответил на вопрос, будьте добры отметить как решение. Если есть вопросы спрашивайте.